# Determine if row from a join is odd or even in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, join

I have a query that returns a row of data for each country as well as the other related information. The query (with everything not relevant removed) looks like so:

```
SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.DateSubmitted) As RowNumber, c.CountryName FROM     Table1 a
inner join Table2 b
on a.id = b.id
inner join Table3 c on c.countrycode = b.countrycode
```

This returns the row number for each row like so:

```
    ID  User        Country     RowNumber
    8   testtest    BANGLADESH  1
    14  testtest    ANGOLA      2
    14  testtest    AUSTRALIA   3
    14  testtest    BANGLADESH  4
    15  testera1    BELIZE      5
    15  testera1    CONGO       6
```

However, I need to return a 0 or 1 for each unique **ID** and not for each row in the main statement I already have. So what I would like to have is the following:

```
    ID  User        Country     RowNumber
    8   testtest    BANGLADESH  0
    14  testtest    ANGOLA      1
    14  testtest    AUSTRALIA   1
    14  testtest    BANGLADESH  1
    15  testera1    BELIZE      0
    15  testera1    CONGO       0
```

I'm pretty weak at SQL and I'm finally making a conscious attempt to improve it, so thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your desired output makes no sense.  Can you explain?

Comment: He wants alternating 0,1,0,1,0,1 for each distinct id, as far as I can tell...

Comment: Ok, maybe the column heading of RowNumber wasn't clear because that's not really what I'm looking for. What I am looking to do is alternate row colors on a report based on the parent records and not the Country or RowNumber. So what I need is an indicator to trigger off of in the report, but I need it to toggle between 0 and 1 for every new ID row.

Comment: Yes Dems, a much more concise explanation :)

Comment: **UGGGGGGGGGGGGGGH.**  Don't put your formatting stuff in the SQL.  If you want alternating colors **DO THAT IN  YOUR REPORT.**

Comment: My answer will do that, using DESNE_RANK(), but you're probably actually better off doing it in your client (itterating through the data and changing the colour when the id transitions).  As a general rule of thumb: keep ALL display related calculations in the client? (*rotfl* @ JNK)

Comment: I understand that much, but there really is no way to do it in the reporting software I am using and the way that I have to display the data. Calm down JNK, go have a beer. I'll buy you one for your troubles.

Comment: Can I have a beer for giving you DENSE_RANK()?  *sulk*

Comment: I agree with @JNK however the flip side is, if you are returning this to many different clients, it may be easier to do the logic once rather than repeat that coding change to every single client. Doing it at the source will at least allow you to fix the applications one by one (if they even have the capability to do custom formatting, which it sounds like rattrick1's does not).

Comment: @Aaron good point but I still hate seeing this in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DENSE_RANK() can be used to give each `id` a different value, but with all occurances of the same `id` having the same value.  Do `% 2` to any number and you get `0` or `1`...

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  c.CountryName
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.DateSubmitted)  As RowNumber,
  (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.ID) - 1) % 2  As StrangeBinaryFlag
FROM
  Table1 a
INNER JOIN
  Table2 b
    ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN
  Table3 c
    ON c.countrycode = b.countrycode
```

Comment: Aye, it's clever that he uses `a.*`, yet there is no `DateSubmitted` in his output.  I just ignored that and gave an example that give 0,1,0,1,0 across distinct ids.  In the vague hope it's what he meant.  if not, no loss to me :)

Comment: Probably need a `PARTITION BY ID` in one or both clauses [untested].

Comment: +1 for trying then I guess.  This is a GIGO question I think.

Comment: Sorry, DateSubmitted is a member of the "a" table, I was just trying to condense down what I was having to post. I will look into DENSE_RANK() now. Thanks and sorry for my very confusing explanations.

Comment: Garbage In, Garbage Out and you get no beer, just a check mark cause that worked like a champ! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Based on your comments, btw, change it to `(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.DateSubmitted, a.ID) - 1) % 2`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the Best Programming Practice & make your life and others' easier:

Rather than returning formatting information in your query, you should figure out how to alternate the row color when your key changes in your display tool.  That's what it's built for and will do the job much easier and more elegantly than SQL ever will.

Comment: I agree and if you are allowed to use a reporting tool that affords you the ability to do what you need to do, you can do it that way, otherwise, you need to find an alternative method.